# Unable to update notification badge count in Android

Tags: java, android, notifications, badge

I am sending NotificationCompat.Builder , it shows notification, but it does not update the count in the app icon badge. The badge is displayed without a count. I am using Android SDK 31. Any help would be appreciated.